# Bulk insert into BigQuery from a CSV gives an error on the timezone format but a direct insert works fine

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timezone

I'm having some trouble with BigQuery and going around in circles with support but it boils down to this.

I have manually entered, handwritten form data I want to get into BigQuery. Later I will be creating some electronic means to replace the paper forms but for the moment I have thousands of rows of data that are largely in excel. I have converted them to CSV, massaged any excel created formatting errors but am stuck when it comes to timezones. BigQuery has 2 formats - timestamp and datetime. The first being a UTC time and the second (after some digging) intended to be just 'what someone would see on a watch' so call it local time.

I can create a table with a field with the datatype of timestamp and do an insert with "2019-12-01 11:34:00 Australia/Adelaide" and it will convert the time to UTC and insert. If I take the exact same value and knock it up in a quick CSV field (manually not through excel) BigQuery will produce an error of 'Unrecognised timezone: Australia/Adelaide; Could not parse "2019-12-01 11:34:00 Australia/Adelaide' as timestamp for field tsfield (position 0) starting at location 0'

To get my historical information in Im probably going to have to give up, convert everything to UTC before I upload just to get it in but Im now concerned about what happens when I try to do this programmatically later too.

edit: For wayward future traveler searching for the same answer... I decided to just convert the values myself for BigQuery and lean into it. I converted all times before uploading into UTC and then let it just apply the timezone stored as a 'timestamp' data type THEN for 'local time' I used the 'datetime' type which does not include a timezone suffix and left it in its original time. I don't have anything telling you where 'local time' is but hopefully can derive from the UTC for most people.

Comment: Have you tried ingesting it as string, then casting in BigQuery later?

Comment: I would recommend you, as Felipe Hoffa suggested, ingest them as string. Then work with them in bigQuery, you could split them into two columns Timestamp and timezone. Would that work for you?